# How to calculate Average based on a criteria on SSAS?

Tags: ssas

I've a Measure like below,

`Year  ProductCategory CompanyId TotalCustCnt SalesAmt  Rank
 2012  Prd1            1         20           100,000   1
 2012  Prd2            1         10            75,000   2
 2013  Prd1            2         18            80,000   2
 2013  Prd2            2         15            50,000   1`

Now I want to calculate three averages out of this data.

Average = SalesAmt / TotalCustCnt

1. Company average (Average for each company)
2. Leader average  (Average for the leader for the Product category,year i.e company with Rank 1)
3. Industry average (Average for the whole industry for the product category,year)

The first one is straight forward, I've added a calculated field in the CUBE for adding an expression (SalesAmt / TotalCustCnt)

But how do I calculate the other two averages?

I've checked the AVG function and also tried SUM([Measures].[SalesAmt].ALLMEMBER) / SUM([Measures].[TotalCustCnt].ALLMEMBER) but no success.

Comment: For Leader Average, look into using FILTER() to use only the Rank 1 rows.  For industry average, you should just be able to divide the measures.   Don't use `ALLMEMBER`.

Comment: Here I've an issue like Rank is a part of the measure. It is not in the dimension. So is there any way to filter then also?
Regarding the industry average, we want the average group by year & product. In that case, will this work SUM([Measures].[SalesAmt]) / SUM([Measures].[TotalCustCnt]) ??

Comment: Yes, please google and learn about the FILTER() function, it is for filtering on measures instead of dimensions.   And yes, if you put that formula on columns, and year and product on rows, that is what you will get.